# Unable to create vpc (public and private subnet)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, vpc

What should I enter in "Elastic IP Allocation ID" to create my vpc. Else its asking for NAT instances. But in neither case I am able to create my vpc.

http://i63.tinypic.com/2akb706.jpg

Comment: Did you create an EIP (elastic ip)?  In the AWS console it is under the EC2 section -> Network & Security.  You'll need one for the VPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are using the VPC Wizard to create a VPC with Public and Private Subnets.

To allow the Private Subnets to communicate with the Internet, the Wizard will also create either a NAT Instance or a NAT Gateway.

Your screen is currently configuring a NAT Gateway, which requires a static IP address for traffic outbound to the Internet. You can **first create an Elastic IP in the VPC console**, then select that Elastic IP in the Wizard when creating the VPC.

If you ever delete the VPC, also delete the Elastic IP to avoid charges (0.5c/hour if an Elastic IP is unused).